# Error with `\Longstack` command

Tags: tables, errors, stackengine

I am getting an error with the following code.  The editor, WinEdt8.0, gives an error message indicating that it does not recognize the command `\Longstack`.  Is there a package that I am missing?

Before it gives this error, it gives me another error:

```
LaTeX error:  File `listofitems.sty' not found
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
```

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."



\begin{document}


\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\stackon{%
\begin{tabular}{|| c !{\vrule width0.8pt} c | c | c||} \hline
    Year        &   1985    &   1986    &   1987 \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
    Store $A$   &   250     &   400     &   750 \\ \hline
    Store $B$   &   500     &   1,000   &   1,250 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}{\bfseries\Longstack{Number of Premium Members}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: the code runs without error in an up to date texlive so just update your tex system to make sure listofitems package is installed.

Comment: @David Carlisle  I got the same errors compiling it on `WinEdt9.0`.

Comment: @David Carlisle May you suggest another command that would get me a similar display for "Number of Premium Members" above the table?

Comment: Winedt is not involved at all, that is just the editor you used to write the file.  You need to update your tex distribution, updating the editor makes no difference.

Comment: it is not clear why you use stack at all here,  just add the text `Number of Premium Members` followed by a blank line before the tabular

Comment: I will update the `TeX` distribution.  I decided to center the title and follow it with a `\smallskip` command.  Thanks.

Comment: Like @DavidCarlisle, the code provided compiles for me, displaying a 3-row, 4-column `tabular`.